# Per element multiplication/addition with numpy arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, slice, numpy-ndarray

I have got a weird problem.

There's an image and I need to recalculate only non zero pixels. And I want to do it via `numpy`, since I process thousands of images and I need it to be fast.

Here's a simplified example with lower dimentiality.

Let's say I have the following matrix:

```
[[0,  0,  1],
 [0,  2,  0],
 [0,  6,  0]]
```

and let's say I want to multiply each value by `2.0` and add `0.5`.

```
matrix = matrix * 2.0 + 0.5
```

The result is:

```
[[0.5,  0.5,   2.5],
 [0.5,  4.5,   0.5],
 [0.5,  12.5,  0.5]]
```

And I want it to be:

```
[[0,  0,   2.5],
 [0,  4.5,   0],
 [0,  12.5,  0]]
```

Obviously I can just do it in a `for` loop with `if pixel == 0: continue` but it would be very slow. And I can't get rid of an addition leaving only the normalization component.

So I have been wondering, can it be done via `numpy`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) in order to choose from x or y depending on a specified condition:

```
a = np.array([[0,  0,  1],
              [0,  2,  0],
              [0,  6,  0]])

np.where(a!=0, a*2. + 0.5, a)

array([[ 0. ,  0. ,  2.5],
       [ 0. ,  4.5,  0. ],
       [ 0. , 12.5,  0. ]])
```

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Wouldn't np.where(np.logical_or(a < -e , a > e), a*2. + 0.5, a) where e is a floating point number close to zero marking the threshold from where one would consider the value to be equal to zero, be better? Or does numpy already account for that and perhaps has a parameter to tune it?

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be:

```
matrix = matrix * 2.0 + 0.5 * (matrix!=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in knowing another way of using `np.where`. Here you check if values are less than 1, assign them to 0

```
matrix = matrix*2 + 0.5
np.where(matrix<1, 0, matrix)
# array([[ 0. ,  0. ,  2.5],
#        [ 0. ,  4.5,  0. ],
#        [ 0. , 12.5,  0. ]])
```